# Simple Syntax Error

Tags: android, syntax-error

I am getting a simple santax error that I can't find the area where to insert a (;) like it asks me to.

```
@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) {
                        System.out.println("Checked");
                        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
                        Drawable icon = null;
                        try {
                            icon = pm
                                    .getApplicationIcon(entry.packageName);
                        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Drawable default_icon = pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
                        if (icon instanceof BitmapDrawable
                                && default_icon instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                            BitmapDrawable icon_bd = (BitmapDrawable) icon;
                            Bitmap icon_b = icon_bd.getBitmap();
                            BitmapDrawable default_bd = (BitmapDrawable) pm
                                    .getDefaultActivityIcon();
                            Bitmap default_b = default_bd.getBitmap();
                            if (icon_b == default_b) {
                                // It's the default icon
                                public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap default_b, int newHeight, Context c) {

                                    final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

                                    int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
                                    int w= (int) (h * default_b.getWidth()/((double) default_b.getHeight()));

                                    default_b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(default_b, w, h, true);

                                    return default_b;
                                }

                                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                default_b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), GridView.class);
                                intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Un-Checked");
                    }

                }
            });

    // return view
    return v;
}
```

I get the error on this line:

```
public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap default_b, int newHeight, Context c) {
```

for my public static Bitmap.

I realize this is probably a simple typing error on my part, but I just am unable to find the location where I need to enter a semicolon.

Comment: You're trying to define a method in the middle of a code block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to declare this method

```
public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap default_b, int newHeight, Context c) {
```

inside another method (your `onClick()`). Move that method outside of the `onClick()` and call it from your `onClick()` if that's what you're trying to do.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   if (addCheckbox.isChecked()) 
   {
      ...
     if (icon_b == default_b) 
     {
      // It's the default icon
        scaleDownBitmap(default_b, someInt, v.getContext());
       // more code
        });

public static Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap default_b, int newHeight, Context c) {

   final float densityMultiplier = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    int h= (int) (newHeight*densityMultiplier);
    int w= (int) (h * default_b.getWidth()/((double) default_b.getHeight()));

    default_b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(default_b, w, h, true);

     return default_b;
   }
```

I did the best I could to show you how it looks with the formatting you had so you will have to fix some things which shouldn't be a problem if you know how your program is suppose to work such as what `params` to pass to the method. Also, you have a `return v` inside your `onClick()` it appears which shouldn't be there. This makes me think that you might have your `onClick()` inside another function which returns a `View` such as `getView()` which wouldn't be right.

Another thing is that your method takes `Context` as a `param` but if it is inside of an `Activity` and called from the `Activity` then you don't need a `Context` variable, you can just use the `Activity Context`.